# How to deal with nested objects which might be string or undefined in a clean way?

Tags: object-oriented, typescript

So I'm parsing an object using Typescript. I am pushing a value from within the object into an array of strings.

Here's the code:

```
if (data.InstanceStatuses != undefined)
            if (data.InstanceStatuses[0].InstanceId != undefined)
                instanceIds.push(data.InstanceStatuses[0].InstanceId as string)
```

I feel there must be a better way to deal with the fact that both `data.InstanceStatuses` and `data.instanceStatuses[0].InstanceId` can be of type `string || undefined`, however I am not sure how to get it down to a simpler statement with less IF blocks.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Typescript has supported [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for a while. To do this concisely *and* avoid the somewhat inelegant `as string` type assertion, extract the possibly nested value into a variable, then check its `typeof` against `string`:

```
const instanceId = data.InstanceStatuses?.[0].InstanceId;
if (typeof instanceId === 'string') {
  instanceIds.push(instanceId);
}
```

This way, `instanceId` will be either the nested value, *or*, if `InstanceStatuses` doesn't exist, it'll be `undefined`. So, it'll only push to the array if the nested value exists *and* the value is a string.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to optional chaining is to make something like this:

```
const optionalChaining = (obj: Object, ...props: string[]) =>
   props.reduce((o: any, prop: string) => (o || {})[prop] , obj);
```

That is:

- Try to access the `prop` in every iteration, even if it returns `undefined`
- In case the previous iteration returned `undefined`, just create an object on the fly to not throw an Error because you're trying to access props of undefined.

See how [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) works, but I like to think that you can use when you want transform an array in one value.

In this case, you want to get an array of props, and get the "chained value" of them or `undefined` if there's not a valid prop among them.

You could use it like:

```
const optionalChaining = (obj: Object, ...props: string[]) =>
    props.reduce((o: any, prop: string) => (o || {})[prop] , obj);

const foo = {
  data: {
    InstanceStatuses: [
      { InstanceId: 'bar' }
    ]
  }
};

console.log(
  optionalChaining(
    foo,
    'data',
    'InstanceStatuses',
    '0',
    'InstanceId'
  )
);

console.log(
    optionalChaining(
        foo,
        'data',
        'InstanceStatuses',
        '1',
        'InstanceId'
    )
);
```

The advantage is that `Array.prototype.reduce` has a good browser compatibility, in other words, is a better cross-browser solution, but I would prefer optional chaining syntax when it will has a good major browsers support.

By other hand, maybe [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining) could be useful if browser compatibility matters for you.